# VB.NET Create a dynamic textbox and have a different function

Tags: vb.net, basic

So here I'm trying to create a dynamic textbox that has a different function per-textbox
but sadly the message box is not working I'm studying selft studying this one and I'm having a hard time. Can anyone tell me what have i done wrong with this one?

```
 Public Function AddNewTextBox() As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    txt.Top = cLeft * 25
    txt.Left = 100
    txt.Text = "TextBox " & Me.cLeft.ToString
    txt.Name = "TextBox" & Me.cLeft.ToString
    cLeft = cLeft + 1
    Return txt
    AddHandler txt.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.text_change


    Dim txt1 As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(txt1)
    txt1.Top = cLeft * 15
    txt1.Left = 90
    txt1.Text = "1 " & Me.cLeft.ToString
    txt1.Name = "TextBox" & Me.cLeft.ToString
    cLeft = cLeft + 1
    Return txt
    AddHandler txt1.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.text1_change
End Function

Private Sub text_change(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("The First Text has Been Change.")
End Sub

Private Sub text1_change(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("The Second Text has Been Change.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the 9th line of the code you posted:

```vb
Return txt
```

When execution hits that line the method completes and no subsequent lines of code are executed. That means that the event handler is not attached to the first `TextBox` and the second one isn't even created.

Why are you returning anything in the first place? You're creating two `TextBoxes` so how does it make sense to return one of them? Make the method a `Sub` and get rid of the `Return` statements or else return both `TextBoxes` together in an array or the like at the end of the method.